# Retrieving data from Firebase database is returning null values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a database in Firebase with rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

And my database is shown in the form of JSON data like this:

```
fieldglass-aeca7
 0 
   age: 23
   name:"shikher"
 1
  age:24
  name:"samarth"

fieldglass-aeca7
  -KWm_3CF1pSVtuy9nhFF
      age:12
      name:"shikhermishra"
  -KWmaVs4frXpS_1lVhcj
      age:13
      name: "Shiker"
```

Now I have written a code to read the data from the database. And also a class User which has 2 data members age,name.

User class is as follows:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;




public class User {

public int age;
 public String name;

 public User(){
 }
 public User(int age,String name)
 {
  this.name=name;
  this.age=age;
 }

 public void setAge(int age) {
  this.age = age;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }


 public int getAge() {
  return age;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
}
```

And my database fetching code is like:

```
FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference=database.getReference("fieldglass-aeca7");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Log.d("user info---@@*******",String.valueOf(user.getAge()));



                assert tv != null;
                assert tv1 != null;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(user.age));
                tv1.setText(user.name);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Log.d("The read failed",databaseError.getDetails());
            }
        });
```

I am trying to fetch the age and name and display it on the 2 `TextView`s I have.

But the output I am getting is

```
user.age=0 and user.name=null.
```

I want to fetch all the data which is present inside :

```
fieldglass-aeca7
......

   fieldglass-aeca7
```

this key value.

I want all the data inside the above path shown. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, The received `DataSnapshot` is like an array, you have to loop for its children first.

The right Scenario might be like this:

```
if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
{
     for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren)
     {
          User user = child.getValue(User.class);

          // your actions here: 
          assert tv != null;
          assert tv1 != null;
          tv.setText(String.valueOf(user.age));
          tv1.setText(user.name);

      }
 }
```

NOTE: `dataSnapShot.getChildren` just returns  `Iterable<DataSnapshot>`, hence no change just loop.